# C++ Making a char array recognise spaces upon input

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make a program that flips the words you input. The problem comes when I try to write the word and it asks twice for the input:

```
cin >> Arr >> myStr;
```

It is logical that it ask twice but everytime I try to use getline the compiler gives out an error (and even if it worked I have to give the input twice) and I need it to include spaces in the character array.

Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string myStr;
string newVal;
int i;

int main()
{
    char Arr[i];
    cout << "Enter: ";
    cin >> Arr >> myStr;

    for (i = myStr.length(); i >= 0; i--)
    {   
        cout << Arr[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The loop works.

The first problem can be corrected by achieving the proper use of getline.

The second one, I have got no idea (use a single input to assign two variables).

Thanks in advance, and I apologise if this is too much of a ridiculous question.

Comment: did you try doing this on two different lines? 
cin>>Arr;
cin>>myStr;

Comment: What is the error that `getline` gives you? And why are you using an array of `char` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: it should give out the same  as cin >> Arr >> myStr;

Comment: @0x499602D2 main_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main_test.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, char [(((long unsigned int)(((long int)i) - 1)) + 1u)])’

Comment: @KoltPenny The problem is that `std::getline` only accepts `std::string`s as its second argument and you're passing in an array of `char`.

Comment: `char Arr[i];` is an error because `i` is an int  (not to mention that it has value `0`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm aware, despite that, my compiler doesn't have a problem with it as the code is right now (as posted). The error comes out when using getline because it ask for specific data. If I give I a value the code messes up.

Comment: @KoltPenny you'll need to post the actual code that you are having trouble with. I can assure that `getline` works properly when used properly..:)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I figured out that giving i a set value makes getline work like shown here: http://pastebin.com/j1E5Dydp but it defeats the purpose of automatically counting the elements inside the array.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Have in mind that it is viable to do with more code (and giving more than one input) but the challenge I proposed to myself was to do it as simple as possible with one input.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Wouldn't `char Arr[i]` be fine since `i` is static?

Comment: @0x499602D2 static has nothing to do with it; `const` is fine and non-const isn't

Comment: @MattMcNabb found the answer, I am just waiting until tomorrow to answer myself. I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Can't a `const` variable still be initialized with a value at runtime?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes it can. I should have said *constant expression* rather than `const`. A variable (static or not) is not a *constant expression* unless it meets all of the following conditions: `const`, non-`volatile`, and was initialized with a constant expression.  [expr.const]/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to have a look to this solution that it's more C++ style than yours:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 int main() {
      std::string myStr;

      std::cout << "Please give me a string: ";

      if(std::getline(std::cin, myStr)) {
           for(std::string::reverse_iterator it = myStr.rbegin(); 
               it != myStr.rend(); 
               ++it) {
               std::cout << *it;
               }

               std::cout << std::endl;

        }


}
```

I suggest to you to use always std::string in C++ because has all the methods and function that you could need. So don't waste your time with char array like you do in C.

Comment: This was actually a better approach. I wasn't aware of the reverse_iterator class. Instead of using the std:: prefix I always prefer using namespace std; but I want to the habit of using the prefix to grow on me, that way I can retain more information about the properties and usage of all references in C++. Thank you very much, I will select this as an answer to the question but I will also publish my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, as I said. I was digging around and came up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string myStr;
int i;

int main()
{
cout << "Enter: ";
getline (cin, myStr);
i = myStr.size();
cout << i << endl;
char Arr[i];

for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++)
{
    Arr[a] = myStr[a];

}

for (i; i >= 0; i--)
{

    cout << Arr[i];

}

return 0;   
}
```

I did not know string contents could also have array-like behaviour. Test it out! Works like a charm (as far as tested).

The way I formatted the code it takes no more than 27 lines of code.

Thanks everyone involved, you helped me a lot.

P.S: Couldn't answer before, I can't do it soon enough with my reputation.